# how to get the position and rotation of controllers and HMD in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I`m dealing with a project in unity to estimate the elbow joints based on the information of HMD as head and shoulder and arm positions and rotations. Therefore, I need these values to be saved in a list of 36. however, I do not have any sensors other than HMD and two controllers.
The question: is there any way to obtain these values and save them in a list?

Comment: Is your question related to the C# programming language, or the deprecated UnityScript programming language? (You've tagged both)

Comment: yes because I need to make a list to save them in c# unity script. and I did edit the question. thank you for mentioning that. @John

Comment: @John UnityScript

Comment: If you're making a new project, I'd recommend switching to C# for Unity since [UnityScript was deprecated in 2017](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/#:~:text=It's%20been%20with%20us%20since,to%20C%23%20in%20Unity%20today.).

Comment: okay, I`d switch the program. @John

Comment: what HMD? what controllers? What values does the device's API provide? I don't know of any reliable way of estimating elbow positions just from the head and hand positions/orientations .. there are many ways I can position my elbow while keeping my head and hand transforms (more or less) the same ...

Comment: @derHugo I suppose, I can use one of the IK solver methods to obtain the upper body joint position and rotations except for the elbow, and then save them in my list. But I am not sure if it`s possible to get these values in real-time when I am using a Vive HMD and two controllers and save them.